# How can I reduce the line to avoid the "too many statically nested blocks"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, block

### SyntaxError: too many statically nested blocks

I'm trying to parse the xml file to csv file.
But I got this SyntaxError when `for...in...` condition is nested more than 20 times.

How can I reduce the line to avoid this SyntaxError?

```
for time in root.findall('A'):
    #print(time.text)
    row=[]
    row.append(time.text)
    for time in root.findall('B'):
        #print(time.text)
        row.append(time.text)
        for time in root.findall('C'):
            row.append(time.text)
            for time in root.findall('D'):
                row.append(time.text)
                for time in root.findall('E'):
                    row.append(time.text)
                    for time in root.findall('F'):
                        row.append(time.text)
                        for time in root.findall('G'):
                            row.append(time.text)
                            for time in root.findall('H'):
                                row.append(time.text)
                                for time in root.findall('I'):
                                    row.append(time.text)
                                    for time in root.findall('J'):
                                        row.append(time.text)
                                        for time in root.findall('K'):
                                            row.append(time.text)
                                            for time in root.findall('L'):
                                                row.append(time.text)
                                                for time in root.findall('M'):
                                                    row.append(time.text)
                                                    for time in root.findall('N'):
                                                        row.append(time.text)
                                                        for time in root.findall('O'):
                                                            row.append(time.text)
                                                            for time in root.findall('P'):
                                                                row.append(time.text)
                                                                for time in root.findall('Q'):
                                                                    row.append(time.text)
                                                                    for time in root.findall('R'):
                                                                        row.append(time.text)
                                                                        for time in root.findall('S'):
                                                                            row.append(time.text)
                                                                            for time in root.findall('T'):
                                                                                row.append(time.text)
for time in root.findall('U'):
                                                                                row.append(time.text)
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

### Update Code

```
head = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    row = []
    for headstr in head:
        for value in root.findall(headstr):
            row.append(value.text)
```

Comment: Why are these nested to begin with?

Comment: You can use generator which yield (returns) next element every time by calling `__next__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever you're trying to do, you're not doing it right. As written, with each loop indented further and further, this would append *all* the `B`s for *every* `A` (so if there were 5 `A` entries and 3 `B` entries, you'd have `A1, B1, B2, B3, A2, B1, B2, B3, A3, B1, B2, B3, A4, B1, B2, B3, A5, B1, B2, B3`). And then *all* the `C`s between every one of those entries, and so on. If the count of each type was even 2, you'd end up with over a million elements in your `list`; at three elements of each type, roughly 3.5 billion entries (enough to exhaust RAM on most home computers), and at four, over a trillion entries (enough to break most supercomputers).

The only sane code I could imagine you intended wouldn't nest the loops at all; just dedent all the loops to the same indentation level, and ideally, make it just a doubly-nested loop, one over things to look for, one over the things found:

```
row = []
for tgt in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T'):
    for time in root.findall(tgt):
        row.append(time.text)
```

That gets all the unique elements of each type exactly once, with far less code, and no combinatoric explosion.

The error you're getting is basically telling you "No reasonable code would ever do what you're doing, rethink your design."

Comment: @flakes: It really isn't feasible though. Sure, you could use `itertools.product` or similar to collapse all these loops into one, but it wouldn't do anything useful for the OP's pattern; the OP's design is nonsensical, and "solving" their stated problem does more harm than good. And, no, even as a generator the OP's makes no sense; it repeats the same outputs many times for no apparent reason, and any *use* of the generator would involve iterations matching the memory usage; avoiding running out of memory for code that won't complete until the heat death of the Universe is pretty pointless.

Comment: @flakes: In short, when the OP has [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040) the correct answer is not to fix their broken Y (the terrible idea for a solution they couldn't make work), but to address X (the problem they thought solving Y would help with, even though Y was a terrible way to deal with problem X).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you for your reply! Your suggestion is the key that I should revise to make it works as I want.